# Copying an array from React Hook

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I'm using the useState hook to populate items in an array.

```
const [meals, setMeals] = useState([]);
useEffect(async () =>{
    const mealsData = await fetchMeals(localStorage.getItem('user_id'));
    console.log(mealsData);// Array(3)
    setMeals([...meals, mealsData]);
    console.log(meals);//[]
 }, []);
```

The array doesn't get copies in my setMeals method, what am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 3):

This is because

```
setMeals([...meals, mealsData]);
```

is an asynchronous call and you are logging the `meals` before being sure the state actually updated

```
console.log(meals);
```

You should call and check your `console.log()` function in another `useEffect()` call which runs on every state change and assures that the state actually changed

```
useEffect(() => {
    console.log(meals);
 }, [meals]);
```

`[meals]` passed as the second argument will let this `useEffect()` run every time `meals` (actually) update.

Comment: What's the solution?

Comment: I edited and added the solution. Let me know if that works...

Answer (score 0):

the update is asynchronous, the new value is not available immediately as you're expecting. You can find an in-depth explanation here: [useState set method not reflecting change immediately](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54069253/usestate-set-method-not-reflecting-change-immediately)

Answer (score 0):

UseEffect cannot be async you should wrap it in an async function

```js
function useMeals() {
   const [meals, setMeals] = useState([]);
    useEffect(() => {
      async function setFetchedMeals() {
        const mealsData = await fetchMeals(localStorage.getItem('user_id'));
        setMeals([...meals, mealsData]);
      }
      setFetchedMeals();
    }, []); // letting the dependency array empty will run the effect only once

  console.log(meals)
  return meals;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are actually not doing anything wrong, state updates are not synchronous, so logging `meals` immediately after updating it will not show the updated value

Use an effect for the `meals` array to detect when it has actually changed...

```
useEffect(() => {
    console.log(meals);
}, [meals]);
```